# Datagridview row filter

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter, defaultview

I am using `DataView` and `RowFilter`. Only one column is filtering,
but I want all columns to be filtered.

I would like to search for a word in the text box to make this filter.

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'" ,textBox1.Text );
    //  dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Date LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}
```

The columns headers `name = Name`, `Date`, and so on.

Comment: What's the problem?!

Comment: my problem.. i want to filter out multiple...

Comment: that is code,, only  "Name" part filtering but i would like to "Name" + others column

Answer (score 3):

Format should be like this for multiple columns;

```
dv.RowFilter = "Column1 = " + value1 + " AND Column2 = " + value2;
```

According to your scenario;

```
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%' AND Date = {1}" ,textBox1.Text, DateValue );
```

Comment: value1... wha't mean?

Comment: it was fail...   i don't understand well...  is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name = '{0}'", TextBoxForSearch.Text);
```

Comment: Try using Code Sample feature

Comment: Your answer should not only include code, but also add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = textBox1.Text;
if(query == string.Empty)
{
    dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
else
{
    (dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name = {0}", textBox1.Text);
    (dgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Date = {1}", textBox1.Text);
}
```